# Swift warning for initializing a deprecated variable

Tags: swift, deprecated

I have two init functions, one of which is deprecated. The variables in the deprecated init are marked deprecated as well. However, when I initialize my object I need to set these to some value which causes Xcode to show the use of deprecation warning. How do I avoid this?

```
struct Example {
    public let x: Int?

    @available(*, deprecated)
    public let y: Int?

    public init(x: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = nil // warning: 'y' is deprecated
    }

    @available(*, deprecated)
    public init(y: Int) {
        self.x = nil
        self.y = y
    }
}
```

I have multiple internal frameworks and I would like to mark a function deprecated not for an iOS version but for our internal API versions.

Comment: I assume in your real case, you can't just use a static initializer for `y`?

Comment: I have old code still using the deprecated init so it still needs to function. So far I resolved this by changing `let` to `private(set) var` and not initializing the variable.